# Populate option set of multiple select statement using data from a table column in Angular Material

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Here's the scenarios:

I have a table that displays dealer information, and one of the columns in the table is agents name.
[image: Dealer table with Agent Name Column]

I'm looking to create a table filter that filters the table based on agent name. For the filter I'm using a Select option set that looks like this.

UI: [image: Filter by agent drop down]

HTML Code for select:

```
<div>
  <button mat-raised-button class="filter"
  (click)=select.open()
  >
  <mat-icon style="margin-right: 5px;">filter_list</mat-icon> 
  FIlter by Agent
</button>
<div class="mat-select-wrapper">
<mat-select #select [formControl]="agentsControl" multiple disableOptionCentering panelClass="myPanelClass">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let agent of agentsList" [value]="agent">{{agent}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</div>
```

TS Code for Select drop down:

```
    agentsControl = new FormControl();
    
    agentsList: string[] = ['John Doe', 'Mary Jane', 'Johannah Kiffin', 'Eldin Astbery', 'Stephen Curry', 'Chris Smith'];
```

Here is the code for the table:
HTML Code:

```
<div flexLayout>
    <mat-card>
        <div class="table-container">
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8"  aria-label="Dealer Queue table">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="dealer_id">
                    <th scope="col" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Dealer #</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el"> {{el.dealer_id}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="dealership_name">
                    <th scope="col" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Dealership</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el"><a [routerLink]="['dreams-account-page',el.dealer_id]">{{el.dealership_name}} </a></td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="agent_name">
                    <th scope="col" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Agent</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el"> {{el.agent_name}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
                    <th scope="col" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>State</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el"> {{el.state}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="phone_number">
                    <th scope="col" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Phone</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el"> {{el.phone_number}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="total_cancellations">
                    <th scope="col" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Cancellations</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el"> {{el.total_cancellations}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="cancellations_over_120_days">
                    <th scope="col" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Cancellations > 120 Days</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el"> {{el.cancellations_over_120_days}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="total_titles_outstanding">
                    <th scope="col" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Titles</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el"> {{el.total_titles_outstanding}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="titles_over_90_days">
                    <th scope="col" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Titles > 90 Days</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el"> {{el.titles_over_90_days}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="last_contact_date">
                    <th scope="col" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Days Since Last Contact</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el"> {{el.last_contact_date | daysSinceToday}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                
                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let dqrow; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="openBottomSheet(dqrow)"></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

TS for table:

```
data: DealerQueueTable[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'dealer_id',
    'dealership_name',
    'agent_name',
    'state',
    'phone_number',
    'total_cancellations',
    'cancellations_over_120_days',
    'total_titles_outstanding',
    'titles_over_90_days',
    'last_contact_date',
  ];

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
  
  private subscriptionToDealerQueueTable : Subscription;

  constructor(private dreamsService : DreamsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscriptionToDealerQueueTable = this.dreamsService.getDealerQueue().subscribe( dealerQueue => {
          this.dataSource.data = dealerQueue;
        })
      }
      
      @ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
      
      ngAfterViewInit() {  
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }
      
      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscriptionToDealerQueueTable?.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
```

Table Model Code:

```
export interface DealerQueueTable {
    dealer_id : number,
    dealership_name : string,
    agent_name : string,
    state : string,
    phone_number : number,
    total_cancellations : number,
    cancellations_over_120_days : number,
    total_titles_outstanding : number,
    titles_over_90_days : number,
    last_contact_date : Date,
    market_manager : string,
    market_manager_phone : string,
    market_manager_email : string
}
```

Both are child components that share a common parent.
Here's an image of the folder structure: [image]

So basically what I'm trying to do and can't figure out how to do is rather than populating the option set array "agentsList" manually, I'm trying to figure out how this can be done dynamically and programmatically? Where all the unique agent names present in table column agent are passed as values to the option set array.

Comment: if you retrieve the table’s full content in one call, then extracting a list of unique agents from the table’s dataSource is easy. Otherwise you will need a separate query returning the unique agent list from the BE

Comment: As per my understanding I am retrieving the table's full content in that one api call in the ngOnInit() function.

Comment: You can `import lodash` and use its `uniq` function to extract a duplicate free list of agents. See https://lodash.com/docs#uniq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I was able to solve this:
In the API call for the table data I retrieved the list of unique agent names and emitted it to the parent component:

**Dealer Table TS:**

```
  @Output() agentData = new EventEmitter<string[]>();
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptionToDealerQueueTable = this.dreamsService.getDealerQueue().subscribe( dealerQueue => {
      //Set the dealerQueue value to this.unfilteredData so we can alter it and still access it later. 
      this.unfilteredData = dealerQueue;
      
      //Call method to set the this.datasource.data based on given filters. 
      this.setDataSource(this.unfilteredData, this.FilterValues?.value || []);
      
      let uniqueAgentList = [...new Set(dealerQueue.map(item => item.agent_name))];
      this.agentData.emit(uniqueAgentList);
    })
    
    this.subscriptionToOptionSetValueChanges = this.FilterValues.valueChanges.subscribe( x => {
      this.setDataSource(this.unfilteredData, x || []);
    });
  }
```

Using the spread (...) operator and Set operator in javascript we are able to get the unique set of values from the data returned by the api. I then emitted this value to the parent component.

**Spread Operator:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

**Set Operator:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

---

**Parent HomeComponent.html**

```
<div fxFlexOffset="2%" >
        <div class="element-header">Dealer Queue Table</div>
        <app-filter #FilterDropdown [agentsListOptions]="agentList"  ></app-filter>
        <app-dealer-queue-table 
        *ngIf = "FilterDropdown?.agentsControl"
        (agentData)="getUniqueAgentData($event)" 
        class="dealerqueuetable"
        [FilterValues]="FilterDropdown?.agentsControl"
        ></app-dealer-queue-table>
    </div>
```

**Parent Home.Component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  agentList = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  getUniqueAgentData(data : any) {
    this.agentList = data;
  }

}
```

The event binding, '(agentData)="getUniqueAgentData($event)', connects the event in the child, this.agentData.emit(uniqueAgentList), to the method in the parent, getUniqueAgentData(data : any) {
this.agentList = data;
}.
Now that we have a unique list of agents stored in `agentList=[];` in our parent component we pass `[agentsListOptions]="agentList"` as in input back to the child `FilterComponent`.
Home.component.html
`<app-filter #FilterDropdown [agentsListOptions]="agentList"  ></app-filter>`

Receive agentListOptions as an input in the filter component:

**filter.component.ts**
`@Input() agentsListOptions: string[];`

And finally use it to populate your dropdown options in the html

```
<mat-select [formControl]="agentsControl" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let agent of agentsListOptions" [value]="agent">{{agent} 
      </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

---